# How to handle Bootstrap pagination inside ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, pagination

I did bootstrap pagination with some duplicate data (with the help of stack overflow member). Its working fine But In my real application I am getting data from database.For that I am using the following method

```
function empRoles() {
       $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "/Admin/getRolesList",
        data:'{}',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (response) {
            console.log(response)
            var roleList = response;
            if (roleList == "") {
                noData()
            } else {
                $('#content').html('');
                for (var i = 0; i < roleList.length; i++) {
                    var table = '<tr  id="' + roleList[i].Id + '"><td>' + (i + 1) + '</td><td class="roleName" id="name' + i + '">' + roleList[i].name + '</td><td><button  class="btn edit btn-info btn-sm" id="edit' + i + '"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>Edit</button><button  class="btn update btn-success btn-sm" id="update' + i + '"><i class="fa fa-floppy-o"></i>Update</button><button class="btn dlt btn-danger btn-sm" onclick="deleteRow(this)" data-dismiss="modal" id="dlt' + i + '"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i>Delete</button><button class="btn editCancel btn-danger btn-sm" id="editCancel' + i + '" ><i class="fa fa-times"></i>Cancel</button></td><tr>';
                    $('#content').append(table);
                    editUpdate();
                }
            }

        },
        failure: function (response) {
            noData()
        }
    });
}
```

Here is my duplicate file without ajax call
https://jsfiddle.net/gjohq4tu/7/

I commented ajax code in my fiddle.Please guys help me, how can I implement bootstrap pagination inside of an ajax call.